# WMTS basemap layer doesn't work in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts

I am trying to use this WMTS link for my country but it doesn't display anything and doesn't show any error either. In ArcGIS everything is ok and works normaly.

Link is : `http://albmaps.asig.gov.al/service/wmts?`

Comment: Do you use a proxy? -> https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using this for the url: http://albmaps.asig.gov.al/service/ows?

[image]

Hopefully this will work for you.

edit - Joseph's answer worked for me too.

Answer (score 10):

1. Set your Project CRS to a relevant CRS (e.g. *EPSG:6870*) and/or enable *OTF*.
2. In the WMS Connection Details, check the `Ignore axis orientation (WMS 1.3/WMTS)` option:

   [image: Configuration]
3. Then add the layers of interest:

   [image: Result]

Comment: you dont need to change the project CRS. Checking "ignore axis orientation" did the trick for me (PRJ CRS is 25832)

Comment: Still, you have of cause a valid point here, when you advise him to change the CRS to one which is appropriate for this area of interested :)